# Lazy evaluation in Haskell with zipWith and two infinite lists

Tags: haskell

Evaluating the Haskell code here:

```
lazee = 0 : zipWith (+) (map (+1) lazee) (map (2*) lazee)
```

and then calling `take 5 lazee` yields this result:

```
[0,1,4,13,40]
```

I don't understand the order in which the above functions are evaluated.  They are infinite lists and I have a bit of trouble wrapping my head around that.  Consequently I'm not sure how Haskell would have gotten this result.

Comment: you can think of a series with `a[n+1]=(a[n]+1)+(2*a[n])`, starting with `a[0]=0`, which is equivalent to `3a[n]+1`.

Comment: @karakfa  Makes sense, thx =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It roughly works like this

```
lazee = 0 : lazee1
lazee1 = zipWith (+) (map (+1) lazee) (map (2*) lazee)
```

therefore

```
lazee = 0 : lazee1
lazee1 = zipWith (+) (map (+1) (0:lazee1)) (map (2*) (0:lazee1))
```

but `map (+1) (0:lazee1)` is `1 : map (+1) lazee1`. Similarly for the other `map`. Therefore

```
lazee = 0 : lazee1
lazee1 = zipWith (+) (1 : map (+1) lazee1) (0 : map (2*) lazee1)
```

Now `zipWith` knows the first elements, and can compute `(+) 1 0`. We get

```
lazee = 0 : lazee1
lazee1 = 1 : lazee2
lazee2 = zipWith (+) (map (+1) lazee1) (map (2*) lazee1)
```

Now repeat the same steps as above:

```
lazee2 = zipWith (+) (map (+1) (1:lazee2)) (map (2*) (1:lazee2))
       = zipWith (+) (2 : map (+1) lazee2) (2 : map (2*) lazee2)
       = 4 : zipWith (+) (map (+1) lazee2) (map (2*) lazee2)
```

And so on.